# How can I have a fixed IP to the randomly selected OpenVPN server?

Tags: routing, openvpn

We currently run a single OpenVPN server with clients that run apps that talk to it via its (unfortunately often) hardcoded IP `10.8.0.1`.

We're switching to multiple OpenVPN servers on the same host, so now clients are in different networks depending on which server they're connected to.

I'm looking for a way for legacy apps running on the clients to still reach their connected server at `10.8.0.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to

1. Add `push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255"` to each server config
2. Run `ip addr add 10.8.0.1/32 dev tun0` for each tun interface on the server

To automate the second part I added the following to each server configuration.

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/up.sh
```

`/etc/openvpn/up.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
ip addr add 10.8.0.1/32 dev $dev
```